# Algorithm for finding the smallest +ve integer greater than a given number that has the same binary weight as given integer

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, time-complexity, permutation

The binary weight of a positive integer is the number of 1's in its binary representation. For example, the decimal number 1 has a binary weight of 1, and the decimal number 7 (which is 111 in binary) has a binary weight of 3.

Given a positive integer N, find the smallest integer greater than N that has the same binary weight as N.

```
public static int compute(int number)   {
    int  count = 0, nextNumber;
    char[] arr =  Integer.toBinaryString(number).toCharArray();
    for(int i =0 ; i < arr.length ;++i) {
        if(arr[i] == '1')
            ++count;
    }
    nextNumber = findNextNumber(number,count);
    return nextNumber;
}
public static int findNextNumber(int number, int weight) {
    char[] arr;
    boolean flag = true;
    int count;
    while (flag) {
        // increment number and convert it into char array
        arr = Integer.toBinaryString(++number).toCharArray();
        count = 0;
        for(int i =0 ; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            if(arr[i] == '1')
                ++count;
        }
        if(count == weight) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

My solution works fine but it's complexity seems to be O(NlogN).Can this be achieved in O(N) or O(log N) by some other approach ?

Comment: You can avoid the roundtrip through string: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation is sometimes called "snoob". Here is a [bunch of approaches from the Hacker's Delight book](http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/snoob.c.txt). Probably the best would be to use Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros which likely compiles to a hardware instruction (untested):

```
int snoob1(int x) {
   int smallest, ripple, ones;  // x = xxx0 1111 0000
   smallest = x & -x;           //     0000 0001 0000
   ripple = x + smallest;       //     xxx1 0000 0000
   ones = x ^ ripple;           //     0001 1111 0000
   ones = ones >>> (2 + Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(x)); //     0000 0000 0111
   return ripple | ones;        //     xxx1 0000 0111
}
```

(there might also be an issue with possible overflow in the "2+" part, since in Java shift counts are modulo 32)

Comment: Thanks @Falk Huffner

Answer (score 0):

You can use algorithm for the next lexicographic permutation. Java implementation for integer array from [here](https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm). Just adapt it to use bits instead of array items:

```
boolean nextPermutation(int[] array) {
    // Find longest non-increasing suffix
    int i = array.length - 1;
    while (i > 0 && array[i - 1] >= array[i])
        i--;
    // Now i is the head index of the suffix

    // Are we at the last permutation already?
    if (i <= 0)
        return false;

    // Let array[i - 1] be the pivot
    // Find rightmost element that exceeds the pivot
    int j = array.length - 1;
    while (array[j] <= array[i - 1])
        j--;
    // Now the value array[j] will become the new pivot
    // Assertion: j >= i

    // Swap the pivot with j
    int temp = array[i - 1];
    array[i - 1] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;

    // Reverse the suffix
    j = array.length - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    // Successfully computed the next permutation
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What would be the behavior in cases where all the bits are Ones only. eg 7, 15

Comment: As per the problem statement, 7 should become 11 not 14.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an approach to achieve the same in O(log N) complexity.

Main steps:-

1. Convert a number into a binary char array.(Pretty simple).
2. Categorize the binary array based on their pattern.(Explained in comments)
3. Based on the category adjust the 0's and 1's of the binary array.
4. Convert binary char array back to a number.

Code:-

```
public static int compute(int number)   {
    int bitPatternCategory , result;
    char[] charArr = Integer.toBinaryString(number).toCharArray();
    bitPatternCategory = determineNumberType(charArr);
    result = findNextDesired(bitPatternCategory, charArr);
    return result;
}
public static int findNextDesired(int bitPatternCategory, char[] arr) {
    int number;
    //System.out.print("bitPatternCategory\t"+bitPatternCategory+"\n");
    char[] temp = new char[arr.length + 1];
    if (bitPatternCategory == 0) {
        temp = getNextForCat0(arr, temp);
    } else if (bitPatternCategory == 1) {
        temp = getNextForCat1(arr, temp);
    } else {
        temp = getNextForCat2(arr);
    }
    number = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(temp),2);
    return number;
}

private static char[] getNextForCat2(char[] arr) {
    // for all cases except cat 0 and 1, for example 110011000,  1001, 1101010
    //  Find first occurrence of 0 after 1 starting from RHS, exchange these bits and then move
    // all remaining 1's(on RHS to the exchanged bits) to RHS of the array
    int j =0,counterForOnes = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if ((arr[i] == '1') && (flag == false)) {
            flag = true;
        } else if ((arr[i] == '0') && (flag == true)) {
            char tempChar = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = tempChar;
            j = i+2;
            break;
        }
    }
    while((j < arr.length) && (arr[j]!='0'))    {
        arr[j] = '0';
        ++counterForOnes;
        ++j;
    }
    while(counterForOnes > 0) {
        arr[arr.length-counterForOnes]= '1';
        counterForOnes--;
    }
    return arr;
}

private static char[] getNextForCat1(char[] arr, char[] temp) {
    // for cases when all ones are on LHS for eg 11100, then add a new bit with value 1 and
    //  shift remaining 1's start from 2nd 1 towards RHS, so 1111 become 10111
    int j = 1,counterForOnes= 0;
    while((j < arr.length) && (arr[j]!='0'))    {
        arr[j] = '0';
        ++counterForOnes;
        ++j;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    temp[temp.length-1] = '0';
    while(counterForOnes > 0) {
        temp[temp.length-counterForOnes]= '1';
        counterForOnes--;
    }
    arr = temp;
    return arr;
}

private static char[] getNextForCat0(char[] arr, char[] temp) {
    // for cases when all bits are ones only, then add a new bit with value 1 and
    //  shift remaining 1's start from 2nd 1 towards RHS, so 1111 become 10111
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = temp.length - 1; i >= 1; --i)
        temp[i] = temp[i - 1];
    temp[1] = '0';
    arr = temp;
    return arr;
}

public static int determineNumberType(char[] arr)   {
    int stateMachine = 0;   //Category 0 for all ones for eg 111, 1111
                            //Category 1 for ones and zeroes  11100, 110000
                            //Category 2 for mix ones or we can say remaining combinations 1011, 11101
    // Assuming MSB will always be 1
    char temp = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; ++i)   {
        if((temp == arr[i]) && (stateMachine == 0)) {
            stateMachine = 0;
        } else if(((temp != arr[i])) && (stateMachine == 0))    {
            stateMachine = 1;
            temp = arr[i];
        }else if(((temp == arr[i])) && (stateMachine == 1)) {
            stateMachine = 1;
        }else if(((temp != arr[i])) && (stateMachine == 1)) {
            stateMachine = 2;
            //temp = arr[i];
            break;
        }
    }   
    return stateMachine;
}
```